# Find the limit of a Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis

Please help me computing this.

> Let $X$ be a measure space with finite measure $\mu(X)$. Let $f\in L^{1}(\mu)$. Compute the limit
>
> $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{X}|f(x)|^{1/n}d\mu(x).$$

I wonder if we could let $f(x)> 1$ then $|f(x)|^{1/n}<f(x)$ where we could use dominated convergence theorem, but I don't know what to do with the other case. Could anyone give me a hint on what theorem should I use?

Comment: Split the space into the sets $\{x:|f(x)|\le 1\}$ and $\{x:|f(x)|>1\}$.

Comment: @Reveillark  when $x\in\{x:|f(x)|>1)\}$ can let $g(x)=f(x)$, but how to deal with $\{x:|f(x)|\leq 1\}$

Comment: *Hint.* Using the [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#The_inequality) or the [Young's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products), we have $$|f(x)|^{1/n}\leq\frac{n-1}{n} + \frac{1}{n}|f(x)|\leq 1+|f(x)|.$$

Comment: @ZiangLi: "but how to deal with $\{x:|f(x)|\leq 1\}$": $|f(x)|\le1$ on that set and the set has finite measure, so...

Comment: @robjohn Sorry but I don't get it.

Comment: @ZiangLi: If a function is less than $1$ on a set with finite measure, say $\mu(X)=m$, what  is the greatest that the integral of that function on that set can be?

Answer (score 1):

As you say
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\lvert f \rvert > 1} \lvert f(x) \rvert^{\frac{1}{n}} d \mu(x)
= \int_{\lvert f \rvert > 1} \lim_{n \to \infty} \lvert f(x) \rvert^\frac{1}{n} d \mu(x)
= \int_{\lvert f \rvert > 1} 1 d \mu(x)
= \mu(\{\lvert f \rvert > 1 \})
$$
by the dominated convergence theorem. On the other hand
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{\lvert f \rvert < 1} \lvert f(x) \rvert^{\frac{1}{n}} d \mu(x)
= \int_{\lvert f \rvert < 1} \chi_{\operatorname{ess\ supp}(f)}  d \mu(x)
= \mu(\{\lvert f \rvert > 1 \} \cap \operatorname{ess\ supp}(f))
$$
again by the dominated convergence theorem, since the constant function identically equal to 1 is integrable on a finite measure space. (Here $\operatorname{ess\ supp}(f)$ is the so-called *essential support* of $f$.) Thus
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int \lvert f(x) \rvert^{\frac{1}{n}} d \mu(x)
= \mu(\operatorname{ess\ supp}(f)).
$$